# How to view contents (File/folders/sub-folders) or open .trd file

Tags: performance-testing, eggplant

I have a performance analysis result which is saved in .trd file.
**Is there any way to open this format?** Or is it some kind of proprietary file which cannot be opened?

Answer (score 0):

The .trd file is actually a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database that can be opened with the likes of [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/sqlitespy/index).

Inside, you will find various tables pertaining to the information captured during the test run.

Here is some example SQL for pulling out network statistics per HTTP request:

**Total bytes received per request:**

```
 select requests.name,SUM(metrics.count) as "Count",SUM(metrics.total) as "bytes received" from requests
 inner join metrics
 on requests.id = metrics.request
 where metrics.id = 3
 group by requests.name
 order by 1,2 desc
```

**Total bytes sent per request:**

```
 select requests.name,SUM(metrics.count) as "Count",SUM(metrics.total) as "bytes sent" from requests
 inner join metrics
 on requests.id = metrics.request
 where metrics.id = 4
 group by requests.name
 order by 1,2 desc
```

Note that the metric IDs in the above may change from 3 & 4 to other values.

Of relevance, there is a new version of Analyzer which was essentially a refresh of the entire component. This new version (v6.1 onwards) actually utilizes a [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) database.